# Generating identical random numbers in sequence after time seed? (Running on my machine)

Tags: go, random

I'm trying to understand precisely why, when called from an external function, my time seeded random number generator returns sequences of identical numbers.

Minimal working example of issue:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

//Generates random int as function of range
func getRand(Range int) int {
    s1 := rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())
    r1 := rand.New(s1)
    return r1.Intn(Range)
}

//Print 100 random ints between 0 and 100
func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        fmt.Print(getRand(100), ", ")
    }
}
```

The output of this is

```
Out[1]: 40, 40, 40, 40, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 34,
34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 47, 
47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 
47,47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 
99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99,
99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99,
```

I'd like to know why this is happening for my own education. I'm also open to suggestions for a solution.

Details: I need to call random numbers in lots of external functions of my code but, like this MWE, when seeded within a function other than main they repeatedly return the same numbers. Additionally, I need to dynamically update the range, so generating lists a priori is not an option. I would rather not have to generate the numbers in main() and pass them into each function-- ranges are calculated inside these and it would complicate things

Comment: Wouldn't have thought of re-seeding an RNG on each call to demonstrate the cost of function calls, but the fact that 47 and 99 show up 32 and 33 times respectively, compared to 34's 19 matches and 10 matching just 12 times indicates CPU level optimisation, perhaps. At any rate, it shows that `fmt.Print` + `getRand` + the 5 calls within `getRand` all happen in under .1 nanoseconds. Don't know why, but I like it when simple code examples hint at what is going on at a lower level. +1 for that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because [`time.Time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time) has a granularity (which is 1 nanosecond) just like your system clock (which might even be multiple milliseconds–depends on many things), and if you call [`time.Now()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Now) multiple times within the greater of these granularities, chances are the returned `time.Time` will be the same, meaning its [`Time.UnixNano()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.UnixNano) method will return you the same nanoseconds (the same number).

And if you use the same number as the seed, the random number generator is ought to return the same numbers.

You only need to seed the RNG once, on app startup, not before each use. You may use a package `init()` function for that, or in the variable declaration:

```
var r = rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()))

//Generates random int as function of range
func getRand(Range int) int {
    return r.Intn(Range)
}

//Print 100 random ints between 0 and 100
func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        fmt.Print(getRand(100), ", ")
    }
}
```

Example output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/fA3aProJUFG)):

> 0, 28, 27, 62, 63, 89, 24, 27, 88, 84, 82, 55, 49, 35, 2, 32, 84, 58, 78, 28, 26, 58, 30, 28, 74, 6, 39, 24, 40, 47, 49, 39, 61, 62, 67, 7, 94, 87, 37, 99, 90, 80, 93, 83, 27, 69, 25, 45, 99, 12, 44, 39, 34, 86, 18, 42, 76, 40, 44, 12, 70, 3, 70, 99, 57, 43, 90, 65, 97, 64, 68, 60, 65, 56, 3, 81, 54, 56, 43, 57, 92, 93, 54, 92, 9, 86, 16, 72, 29, 12, 97, 87, 55, 42, 87, 41, 94, 53, 23, 64,

One thing to note here: [`rand.NewSource()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#NewSource) returns a source which is not safe for concurrent use. If you need to call `getRand()` from multiple goroutines, you need to synchronize access to `r`, or use a separate [`rand.Rand`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Rand) in each goroutine.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I do plan on spinning go threads, so I'm wondering if synchronized access would reduce efficiency gains obtained through concurrency?

Comment: @kapaw Yes, synchronization will make it somewhat slower, but that doesn't mean your app will be slower. Measure. Also if you create and use a separate `rand.Rand` for each goroutine, you don't need to use synchronization.

Comment: So I'd have to globally define each one?

Comment: @kapaw It doesn't matter how you store them, it doesn't have to be global variables, but each such goroutine should have its own, that is only used by a single goroutine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a Go expert but I think the problem is a generic programming issue. It is related to the fact you set the seed to each call. The seed is based on time function. So what is happening is that in a very short time, you have a number of calls while the time is not changed (yet) and so you get the same value because you are setting the same seed again and again.

Try to set the seed, *once only* and *outside* the `for` loop of calls.